# An evil idea for nasty mathematician: making up coefficients for N-variable equation so that it would have a single solution for variables == 0, 1.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinations, diophantine-equations

An evil idea came to my mind. I promise you I won't use it :-D

Today online I've seen sort of a test:

- Stole from a shop: 10 points
- Had a threesome: 20 points
- Cheated on a girlfriend: 15 points
  ...

One is supposed to sum all of his points and post a sum he/she's got for fun.

And here I thought... What if it is possible to make up a number of such weights so that for variables that only can be either 0 or 1 equation would have only ONE solution for any sum that can be acquired?

I mean, from the example above, 10*x+20*y+15*z+...=SUM would have only one solution for x,y,z from [0, 1].

How would you search that 10, 20, 15,... coefficient list?

Been thinking about it for like 3 hours already. It consumes me :-)

Don't suggest something like "powers of X" weights or "use prime numbers and multiplication instead of sum", it is kinda too easy to understand :-)

EDIT: also, for "powers of X" weights would differ way too much, so it wouldn't look okay, that would raise suspicions for potential victim :-)

Comment: Rather than powers of 2, you can use any sequence $a_i$ where each element is greater than the sum of the preceding ones.  For example, $1, 2, 5, 9, 18, 40, 76\ldots$.  To decode, just apply a “greedy” decomposition: from the total score, repeatedly deduct the largest possible one of the $a_i$.  Continuing the example, if the score is 131, you deduct 76, leaving 55, then 40, then 9, 5, and 1. You can also use this technique in combination with wimi's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your reason to forbid powers of 2 is that the coefficients are too obvious, you can always add a larger power of $2$ to all the coefficients. For example, if you have 4 coefficients, you just choose
$$2^A+2^0\ ,\ 2^B+2^1\ ,\ 2^C+2^2\ ,\ 2^D+2^3$$

where $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are *any* integers greater or equal to $4$ (number of coefficients), possibly repeated. In this way, you can choose for example

$$33x+ 18y+ 20z+ 40t$$

where I set $A=D=5$ and $B=D=4$. Those numbers look less obvious than powers of $2$.

You can extend this to higher bases, optionally with additional multiplying factors smaller than the base (i.e., $2\cdot 3^A$, etc.).

With these methods, you can still easily read off the $(x, y, z, t)\in[0,1]$ unknowns from the last digits of the binary (or higher-base) representation of the result.

Comment: Pretty nice idea, I'd say! Thanks :-)